# What is a visible example for a mandatory access control (MAC)

Tags: mandatory-access-control

I can see clearly how discretionary access control (DAC) works by checking the properties of a file on my MSWindows machine, the file has attributes and the owner of the file can do almost anything with it like making it available for everyone to read, transfer the ownership to an other user or even delete it

However I cant find any visible example that I can actually see in a GUI that might help me to understand how mandatory access control (MAC) works? can I create a file under MAC? How does the file get its attributes? and how is it possible that I don't own it?

Comment: Is the question specific to Windows?

Comment: No, I was just referring to the fact that I can see how DAC works on Windows for example

Comment: From [Maharashtra state board of technical education model answers](http://msbte12.msbte.org.in/ems_s13/ems_th/model_answer_lot1/REVISED-12177.pdf): > Mandatory Access control (MAC): It is used in environments where different levels of
security are classified. It is much more restrictive. It is sensitivity based restriction, formal
authorization subject to sensitivity. In MAC the owner or User can not determine whether
access is granted to or not. i.e. Operating system rights. Security mechanism controls
access to all objects and individual can not change that access.

Comment: You can find a long list of implementations of Mandatory Access Control [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control#Implementations).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of places that you can see Mandatory Access Control (MAC) systems in operation in consumer OSs, that spring to mind.

[SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page) is installed on a number of linux distributions and can be set in enforcing mode which would show an example.

Also windows [Mandatory Integrity Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb648648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are another example.

Seeing an example of this could be done by getting a Windows 8 machine and trying to modify files within a windows 8 store programs installation directory (under the hidden directory c:\program files\windowsapps).  Even as an administrative user you will be prevented from changing these files via standard OS tools even after you have "taken ownership" of the file, which in a DAC system would usually allow you to modify it..

Comment: I don't find the "ownership" reason justified in parlance with MAC. Does MAC mean "privilege" on Windows? "Take Ownership" is a privilege, which can be assigned to users also. Where MAC is coming into picture?